# The python script in Azure Function is working but for some reason the data is invisible

Tags: python, excel, azure

I am creating a script to convert CSV to xlsx in python using Azure Function through VS CODE Extension. The below mentioned code is executing without any problem. But the file output by the code isn't opening and it shows the error as

'Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file'

```
import logging

import time

import pandas as pd

import azure.functions as func

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

import os

 

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

filename = req.params.get("name")

# The following line is either a comment or an assignment, fix it as needed:

# filename = "input.csv"



STORAGEACCOUNTURL = 'URL'

STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = 'KEY'

LOCALFILENAME = '/tmp/' + str(filename)



CONTAINERNAME = 'demo'

BLOBNAME = str(filename)



# Download from blob

t1 = time.time()

blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)

blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME)

with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:

    blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()

    blob_data.readinto(my_blob)

t2 = time.time()



df = pd.read_csv(LOCALFILENAME)

targetFilename = filename.replace('.csv', '.xlsx')

print(targetFilename)

df.to_excel('/tmp/' + targetFilename, header=True)

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))

print(ROOT_DIR + '/' + LOCALFILENAME)

container_client = blob_service_client_instance.get_container_client(container='demo')

with open(file=os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, LOCALFILENAME), mode="rb") as data:

    blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name=targetFilename, data=data, overwrite=True)

return func.HttpResponse('success')
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I made some changes to your code and was able to convert the CSV file to an xlsx file. Also, see the xlsx blob file data.***

I uploaded a **CSV** file to the storage account container as below:

[image]

**Code** :

```py
import os
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    filename = req.params.get("name")
    if not filename:
        return func.HttpResponse("Error: 'name' parameter is missing or empty.", status_code=400)

    STORAGEACCOUNTURL = 'https://<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net'
    STORAGEACCOUNTKEY = '<storage_key>'
    CONTAINERNAME = '<container_name>'
    BLOBNAME = str(filename)

    LOCALFILENAME = os.path.join(os.environ["TMP"], filename) 

    blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
    blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME)

    with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
        blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
        blob_data.readinto(my_blob)

    df = pd.read_csv(LOCALFILENAME)
    targetFilename = filename.replace('<csvFileName>.csv', '<xlsxFileName>.xlsx')
    excel_file_path = os.path.join(os.environ["TMP"], targetFilename)
    df.to_excel(excel_file_path, header=True)

    container_client = blob_service_client_instance.get_container_client(container=CONTAINERNAME)
    with open(excel_file_path, mode="rb") as data:
        blob_client = container_client.upload_blob(name=targetFilename, data=data, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f'Success: Converted and uploaded {targetFilename}')
```

**requirements.txt** :

```py
azure-functions
pandas
openpyxl
azure-storage-blob
```

**Output** :

[image]
[image]

**Output at Browser** :

[image]

**Azure Portal** :

***The xlsx file was uploaded successfully to the storage container. ***Then, I clicked on download to check the xlsx file data as below,******

[image]

**xlsx Output data** :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, the code works properly now and the output is visible.

Comment: Hello @Dasari_Kamali, the code is working on local, but is not working on the Azure Portal. Getting HTTP 500 error. Could you please help me with this.